# CSS - font-size in ems with typographic baseline grid

Tags: css

I'm using a fluid baseline grid template as a starting point for a site I'm working on and am hoping for a pointer on typography. The CSS font-size declaration is set by the grid template as follows:

```
/* DEFAULT FONT SETTINGS */
/* 16px base font size with 150% (24px) friendly, unitless line height and margin for vertical rhythm */
/* Font-size percentage is based on 16px browser default size */
    body, button, input, select, textarea {font: 100%/1.5 Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; *font-size: 1em; color: #333}
```

I'm wary of adjusting this setting but if I need the default font to be smaller than this. If I leave the declaration above as is, then set all p, a, ul fonts to be .9em for example, then this (expectedly) results in font sizes decreasing relative to their parent element. I don't think I should be setting the font size in pixels either - so can anyone advise a good solution for this (probably very simple!) issue?

Comment: It sounds like you are trying to resize the grid without affecting the size of everything else (p, a, ul). Since all of the sizes are percentages of the default scale, you will have to recalculate the correct percentage for each affected element.

Answer (score 1):

I have just reduced the px down from 24px to 20px seams to work fine, are you using the Drupal theme?, and if so have you got it to work in IE 6-8, it breaks and displays in 1 column see the drupal demo site in IE to see http://themes.arborwebdevelopment.com/fluid-baseline-grid-theme-demo

This is a issue I've been trying to work out for a month now.